# How to use MassTransit.MongoDb nuget package?

Tags: mongodb, masstransit

There is a new package made by Chris Patterson, but I did not find any sample of use or some documentation yet ...

This package is to configure Masstransit with mongoDb!

Anyone knows how to use or configure it?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.MongoDb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guys at Liberis Labs created the message data and saga repository, so it's best to check with them. They did write a blog post about it: http://liberislabs.com/2016/02/28/sharing-large-messages-between-your-services-with-masstransit-and-mongodb.html

For the saga repository, it works like any other and you can take a look at the unit tests to verify how to use it.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/develop/src/Persistence/MassTransit.MongoDbIntegration.Tests/Saga